# Orderby Custom Field (What is wrong?)

Tags: orderby

This is a simple event listing. I want the output to list by "touring date" which is a custom date field. However, it doesn't seem to work.

```
  {exp:channel:entries channel="touring_calendar" dynamic="no" orderby="touring_date_and_time" sort="asc"}
  <div class="touring-details">
    <h2 class="touring-city">{touring_city_state}</h2>
    <h2 class="touring-show">{touring_show_name}</h2>
    <h2 class="touring-venue">{touring_venue_name}</h2>
    <h2 class="touring-date"> {touring_date_and_time  format=" %F %j, %Y; %g:%i %a"}</h2></div>
  {/exp:channel:entries}
```

It seems to be listed by "entry date" not the custom date field I created. I am stuck!

Comment: Well syntax seems good to me. You can raise a support ticket on Elislab

Comment: Can we assume the field type is actually set to "date"?

Answer (score 0):

So I ran a test for you. I added a date field to a channel in my sandbox.
I added this data to several entries. I can control the ordering based on that field with:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages" orderby="datetest" sort="asc"}
{count} - {title}<br/>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This works as expected. You can watch the order flip when the sort parameter is changed.